# How to handle the static folder in deno

Tags: typescript, static-files, deno

I would like to know if it's possible to change the static resource file depending on the URL.
For example, here is my folder pattern :

```
/root
-> server.ts
-> /project**s**
    -> some libraries used in index.html files
    -> /project1
       -> index.html
       -> some files used in the index.html
    -> /project2
       -> index.html
       -> some files used in the index.html
```

and this is how to handle static files in deno using the oak library :

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {    
    await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
        root: `${Deno.cwd()}/static`,
    })

    next()
});
```

My goal is when you type in the URL : *mydomain.com/project/project1*
return you the *index.html* file corresponding to the project id.

For now, I'm using oak router to redirect URLs like that:

```
const router = new Router();
router.get('/project/:project_id', project)
```

```
export const project = async (ctx: RouterContext) => {
    ctx.render(`${Deno.cwd()}/project**s**/` + ctx.params.projectid + '/index.html');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

**Example:** Dynamically check for existing folders, if not found you'll get error: `No such file or directory (os error 2)`

```
.
├── projects
│   └── foo
│       └── index.html
└── server.ts
```

```js
// ./server.ts

import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use(async (context) => {
    await context.send({
        root: Deno.cwd(),
        index: "index.html",
    });
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

```html
// ./projects/foo/index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```sh
deno run --allow-net --allow-read=. server.ts

# or /foo, /foo/index.html
curl localhost:8000/projects/foo/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```